# Setting arbitrary axis value for a contour plot of form (x,y,f(x,y))?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, contour

So I have a data set that is in the matrix form:

```
x1, Y1, VALUE1
x2, Y1, VALUE2
x3, Y1, VALUE3

x1, Y2, VALUE4
x2, Y2, VALUE5
x3, Y2, VALUE6
```

and so on. I get my contours properly except my x and y axes go from say 1, 2, 3...N. This is fine because it is representing pixels so isn't incorrect, but I would like to change the axes values from pixels to the actual units. I can't seem to find a way to instruct contour to allow me to add this.

```
bsquare=np.reshape(value,(x length,y length))
blue=contour(bsquare,colors='b')
plt.show()
```

where xlength and ylength are the number of points in either axis.

Comment: Personally, I don't understand this question.  If you provided a working example, with data that you generated or wrote down it would be helpful.  eg, the axes aren't representing x and y correctly, but you don't specify what they are or what they should be; is there any significance to the data being in triplets; typical contour plots don't have integer axes ( http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html ), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.contour` can be given arrays `X, Y, Z` then it takes the `Z` as the contour values and the `X` and `Y` are used on their respective axes. Here is a script that first makes some data to play with, then gets into an array of the form you describe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make some test data 
nx = 2
ny = 3
x = np.linspace(0, 3, nx)
y = np.linspace(50, 55, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sin(X) + Y

# Now get it into the form you describe
data = [[[x[i], y[j], Z[j, i]] for i in range(nx)] for j in range(ny)]
data = np.array(data)
print data

>>> 
[[[  0.          50.          50.        ]
  [  3.          50.          50.14112001]]

 [[  0.          52.5         52.5       ]
  [  3.          52.5         52.64112001]]

 [[  0.          55.          55.        ]
  [  3.          55.          55.14112001]]]
```

Note I am using a `numpy.array` not just a normal list this is important in the next step. Lets split up that data as I presume you have done into the x and y values and the values themselves:

```
# Now extract the data 
x_values = data[:, :, 0]
y_values = data[:, :, 1]
values = data[:, :, 2]
```

Now all of these things are `nx, ny` arrays, that is they have the same shape as your `bsquare`. You can check this by printing `values.shape` and changing the integers `nx, ny`. Now I will plot three things:

1. Firstly as you have done simply contour plot the values, this automatically adds the axes values
2. Secondly I plot using the arrays to give the correct scalings and
3. Finally I will plot the origin data set to show it properly recovers the data.

You will need to compare the axis values with where the fake data was created:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(10, 2))
axes[0].contour(values)
axes[1].contour(x_values, y_values, values)
axes[2].contour(X, Y, Z)
```

[image]

How you implement this will largely depend on how you have imported your data. If you can simply turn it into a `numpy.array()` then I think this will solve your issue.

Hopefully I understood your problem correctly.